# how to open ede projects after closing emacs

Tags: emacs

I've tried to find an answer to this specific question but had no luck. Or maybe I'm simply asking the wrong question.

To keep it simple: I follow the emacs' EDE Quick Start guide. Everything flows just fine and I get the expected results.
The problem arises when i close emacs and try to open the project again.
At that point I get the infamous "Corrupt object on disk" error.

I see it can be used another kind of project (ede-cpp-root-project) but it lacks all basic functionalities that should be hand-made, but that's not what I'm interested in. I would like to use ede-proj-project.

I'm interested in understanding why this happens. Why I can't open a project that worked just fine before closing emacs? What's changed just by closing emacs?
Am I missing something?

FYI: If it is useful information, I'm using emacs version 25.3.1 but I've tried few other earlier versions with the same result.

PS: As you can probably tell, I'm not really skilled so, please, forgive me if it is an annoying question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Copy this into your .emacs startup configuration file

```
(require 'cedet)
(require 'eieio)
(require 'eieio-speedbar)
(require 'eieio-opt)
(require 'eieio-base)
(require 'ede/source)
(require 'ede/base)
(require 'ede/auto)
(require 'ede/proj)
(require 'ede/proj-archive)
(require 'ede/proj-aux)
(require 'ede/proj-comp)
(require 'ede/proj-elisp)
(require 'ede/proj-info)
(require 'ede/proj-misc)
(require 'ede/proj-obj)
(require 'ede/proj-prog)
(require 'ede/proj-scheme)
(require 'ede/proj-shared)
```

I found the solution here:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17950/ede-load-project
which lead to CEDE project:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CEDET_Quickstart

It worked for me. - GNU Emacs 25.2.2